Agent state resets after going through Batch block - Anylogic
I have an agent that goes through a statechart that has 4 states. Each of the states affects how the agent looks visually. After reaching the 4th state (finalized), the agent goes through a Batch block that releases a batch of 5 agents, but on exit the batched agents reverse to the 1st state and therefore look different.
How can I maintain the "finalized" state when exiting the Batch block? I imagine there has to be a simple way to do this but I can't find it in the documentation.
As a workaround, is there a way to send the agent back to the "finalized" state? Something like "send("nextState",agent);" but to send to a specific state? Thanks for the help.
EDIT: the permanent batch parameter is set to false, which means I am creating a temporary batch, but still the Agents revert to the 1st state when exiting the batch block. After further testing, I found that when you unbatch, then the Agents appear again on the 4th state, which means that they are just reverted to the 1st state while they are batched.


You are setting the Batch block wrongly, see the help:

Instead of creating a permanent batch, create a temporary batch. This preserves the actual agents, and thereby their states.
(In your case, you actually create new agents upon unbatching, hence restarting the statechart)

Thank you for the answer, Benjamin. I had looked at the documentation earlier, but I am not creating a Permanent batch, I am creating a Temporary batch,  but still the agent reverts to the first state when exiting the batch block. I have edited the original question with the image of the batch properties, in case you can take a look. Thanks!

have you tested this with a simple example model? If so, it may be a bug. Try it: simple agent type with 2 states, send them into state 2, then batch (temporary), then unbatch and check which state they are in

Thank you, Benjamin. I did the test and indeed I think that this is a bug. The test: agents get sent to state 2, they enter a temporary batch block and when exiting they are reverted to state 1, then they go through an unbatch block which sends them back to state 2 again. In other words, they are just reverted to state 1 while they are batched.

I do not believe this to be a bug. The agent that exits the Batch block has no need to be any of the batched agents (even if temporary). Thus, the agent exiting the batch block (after batching) is a completely new SolarPanel, not one of the existing agents.
Actually, I find it counter intuitive that 4 SolarPanel make one SolarPanel. Maybe it should be 4 SmallSolarPanel batch into one BigSolarPanel, or 4 SolarPanel batch into one PalletOfSolarPanel. This way, it would be more clear why the agent exiting the batch is NOT one of the solar panels of the input

Yeah, it's up for discussion. However, in my view, what a Batch block does is just putting X number of agents together and treating it as one agent. In the case of the temporary batch, it can even be unbatched later, and therefore the properties of the original agent (in this case the state) should be maintained. Regarding your example, it´s not a matter of size, it´s a matter of agent numbers. 4 Solar Panels make up 1 batch of Solar Panels, but the original Solar Panel is the same.

The Batch block you put X agents together and generate a NEW agent that holds the individual agents. It does not batch 4 agents into the first, or batch 4 agents into the last. It bached 4 agents into the new agent.
If you want to "add" agents into another, the operation you are looking for is Pickup (https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/pickup.html). In this case, the "container" agent holds the other agents but the "container" agent is kept at the output.
Batches expected behavior is "from 3 granola bars, make one box of granola bars" or similar.
